# How can get the size screen of laptop when need to use flutter_screenutil package in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I use the flutter_screenutil backage when develop the application on app and I want to use the flutter_screenutil in flutter web I use the size in the resolution of monitor but it does not get the correct size
how can I use flutter_screenutil in web and how can get the size to but it in designSize for the flutter_screenutil package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

You can use the above code without using any package

Comment: You should probably switch to doubles instead of ints here

Comment: Is I can use this solution for all pages as separated widgets or add the height and the width in every pages

Comment: The best thing you can do is to create a constants file and declare your height and width there, then you import your constants file in the page you want to use the height an width then you can use it

Answer (score 0):

If you use Get Package then it will be easy

```
double height = Get.height; 
double width = Get.width;
```

otherwise material way is

```
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height; 
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

Comment: Is I can use this solution for all pages as separated widgets or add the height and the width in every pages